# Environment variables validation with class-validator in nestjs?

Tags: typescript, environment-variables, nestjs, class-validator, class-transformer

How can i validate my environment variables via class-validator in nestjs? There is no example in the official documentation, only with joi. But for the DTO you pretty much limited with class-validator because interfaces do not compile in runtime, etc. And i don't want to use two different validators across my app.

Comment: Might you provide an example of your environment variables and how you want to validate them?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an Environment schema class using `class-validator`:

```js
// environment.ts
import {Injectable} from '@nestjs/common';
import {IsFQDN, IsString} from 'class-validator';

@Injectable()
export class Environment {

    @IsFQDN()
    DATABASE_HOST: string;

    @IsString()
    DATABASE_USERNAME: string;

    @IsString()
    DATABASE_PASSWORD: string;

}
```

Then add a custom provider to your module that will validate `process.env` against `Environment`.

```js
// app.module.ts
import {Module} from '@nestjs/common';
import {transformAndValidateSync} from 'class-transformer-validator';

import {Environment} from './environment';

@Module({
  imports: [
      // Imports
  ],
  controllers: [
      // Controllers
  ],
  providers: [
      {provide: Environment, useValue: transformAndValidateSync(Environment, process.env)}
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Now you should be able to inject `Environment` to access all of your environment variables.